# Materialize chips not displayed corectly in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, materialize

I'm trying to style chips from Materialize template to look like this: [image: Wanted output]

My chips now look like this in Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

And like this in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

As you can see the problem is in Chrome that chips are hiding behind the user circle and in firefox the user circle is not shown at all and the "X" is out of the chips...
**Where have i gone wrong with my code??**
**Note that I am using Meteor and Materialize framework**

Code (Chips template written in Meteor):

```
    <div class="flex" style="display:inline;">
     {{#if fcFilterActive}}
      {{#each fcFilterActive}}
     <div class="chip" style="background-color:#E0E0E0; margin-bottom:2px;">
     {{title}}: {{operator}} {{value}} {{operator2}} {{value2}}
     <i id="chipFilterClose" class="material-icons fc-filter-clear" style="">close</i>
     </div>
      {{/each}}
     <div class="chip" style="background-color:#E0E0E0; margin-bottom:2px;">
     Reset all filters
     <i class="material-icons fc-filter-reset" style="">close</i>
     </div>         
    {{/if}}
    </div>
```

And here is how I call the template:
NOTE: The "toolBarUsers flex" is the template for user/member and the "boardOption" are those three dots that open an exta window... I included the code for this just in case :)

```
<div class="boardChips">
            {{> Filter filterChips=true onlyChips=true template="Contacts_list_all" fcFilterActive=fcFilterActive2}}
            </div>

            <div class="toolBarUsers flex" style="display:flex; float:right;">    
              {{#each member in BoardMembers}}  
                <div class="other-profile" style="margin-top:4px; background-color:#f06292;">
                  <span>{{member.profile.initials}}</span>                  
                </div>
              {{/each}}
            </div>    
            <div class="boardOption">
                <a class='dropdown-button-board' href='#' data-activates='boardOptions{{board._id.valueOf}}'><i
                        class="material-icons icon-black">more_vert</i></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is your firefox and chrome up to date? You can check the supported versions from here https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül yes my Firefox and Chrome are the latest versions...

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or a clonable repo? This looks weird.

Comment: @Almaju i dont realy know how to create a JSFiddle for this... since recreating this code in JSFiddle did not work for me... the basic chips code from Materialize website doesent wrok... or I'm just not doing it right haha xD